# Missing one value in a for loop probably because the list ends with ' '

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, for-loop

I'm analyzing a sound and trying to get all the amplitudes of the sound with a for loop (which are in hexadecimal and then I convert them to integers) but when I print the length of the list I'm one value short. I also get an error message :

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

but only if I loop with: `for i in range(sample)`.
Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
data = sound.readframes(1)
list = []

stream.write(data)

sample = sound.getnframes()
var = 0
for i in range(sample - 1):
    stream.write(data)
    var = int(binascii.hexlify(sound.readframes(1)), 16)
    if var > 127 :
        var = var + 1 - (2**8)
    list += [var]

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

print list
print len(list)
```

Comment: `range(sample)` is correct, but does `sound.getnframes()` include the sample you already read in the first line?

Comment: Oh you are right, it was the first one which was missing, thanks